# Is "in" before "losing" correct in the following phrases?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositional-phrases

Sample #1: I am interested in doing the sport, and *in losing* weight.

Sample #2: I am interested in doing the sport and *in losing* weight. (comma deleted before and)

Question: Is placing *in* before *losing* is correct in two phrases above?

Comment: The word you want is "losing", not "loosing".

Comment: Yes, *in* before *losing* is correct, but *the* before *weight* is incorrect (unless you had e.g. a specific barbell you just couldn't seem to ditch).

Comment: If i delete the "comma" before and, the following phrase would be correct? I am interested in doing the sport and in losing weight.

Comment: @Eli Nothing will be correct until you delete the *the* from before *weight*. Do that first.

Comment: @DanBron:  Respectfully disagree.  If "the" is left in place, there is an implied subordinate:  *I am interested in doing the sport, and in loosing the weight (that will result from doing the sport.)*

Comment: @cobaltduck Only if "the" weight has been topicalized, which is hasn't in this context. This is set in a general context, discussing what our interests are. And generally speaking l, it is overwhelmingly more common to say "lose weight" than "lose the weight".

Comment: *The* before *weight* is not "incorrect", and it certainly can refer to body weight and not just to a barbell as the commenter above suggests, but you need a proper context to justify the use of *the*.  You almost always need context to discuss the use of articles, and we have no context here, so we can't have a meaningful discussion about whether *the* is appropriate.  (That is probably what the commenter means when he says 'if "the" weight has been topicalized', but *topicalize* is a technical term that doesn't make sense here.)

Comment: I know this wasn't the part of the sentence you asked about, but "doing the sport" is not something a native speaker would say.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your sentences as they currently stand.  The comma is unnecessary but does not make the sentence incorrect.

In general, you will **lose weight** by participating in ***the*** **sport** *of your choice*.  In particular you will lose ***the*** **weight** which you have gained through years of inactivity.

Comment: Change *loose* to *lose*, here.

Comment: Thank you! I was just wondering if "in" is extra before losing? I mean, deleting "in" before "losing" will make the sentences wrong?

Comment: You can delete **in** before losing and it will be understood. You can delete both **in**s and it will still be fine. Having both **in**s there or both not gives it more **parallel construction**, but keeping the first one and deleting the second will easily still be understood

Comment: @Eli Please be careful; the information Peter has given you in his comment is incorrect.  You cannot delete both *in*s.  *I am interested doing the sport and losing weight* isn't a valid way to rephrase *I am interested in doing the sport and in losing weight*.  You can remove the second *in*, although a good answer might suggest whether the meaning changes if you do so.